# Keeping track of a (child) struct who called a method in Rust

Tags: rust, lifetime

I would like to create a `add_ten` method for `MyStruct` which keeps track of the child that called it (as a reference).

```rust
struct MyStruct<'a> {
    value: i32,
    child: Option<&'a mut MyStruct<'a>>,
}

impl MyStruct<'_> {
    fn add_ten(&mut self) -> MyStruct {
        MyStruct {
            value: self.value + 10,
            child: Some(self),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = MyStruct { value: 10, child: None }; // Create some struct
    let b = a.add_ten(); // Process it and return the new struct with a ref of the child who called it
    
    println!("{}", a.value); // Be able to read the value here
    println!("{}", b.value); // and here
}
```

However I get this error:

```rust
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:10:9
   |
9  |       fn add_ten(&mut self) -> MyStruct {
   |                  ---------
   |                  |
   |                  let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
   |                  has type `&mut MyStruct<'2>`
10 | /         MyStruct {
11 | |             value: self.value + 10,
12 | |             child: Some(self),
13 | |         }
   | |_________^ associated function was supposed to return data with lifetime `'2` but it is returning data with lifetime `'1`
   |
   = note: requirement occurs because of the type `MyStruct<'_>`, which makes the generic argument `'_` invariant
   = note: the struct `MyStruct<'a>` is invariant over the parameter `'a`
   = help: see <https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html> for more information about variance
```

I understand that its a lifetime error, but I'm kind of stuck here :) I hope what I'm asking is clear enough, any help is appreciated!

**EDIT**

The reason I would like to use a reference, is to be able to come back to the childs and modify them. Something looking like this:

```rust
struct MyStruct<'a> {
    value: i32,
    child: Option<&'a mut MyStruct<'a>>,
}

impl MyStruct<'_> {
    fn add_ten(&mut self) -> MyStruct {
        MyStruct {
            value: self.value + 10,
            child: Some(self),
        }
    }

    fn set_childs_to_zero(self) {
        if self.child.is_none() { return; }
        let mut child = self.child.unwrap();
        
        loop {
            child.value = 0;
            if child.child.is_none() { break; }
            child = child.child.unwrap();
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = MyStruct { value: 10, child: None }; // Create some struct
    let b = a.add_ten(); // Process it and return the new struct with a ref of the child who called it
    
    println!("a: {}", a.value); // 10
    println!("b: {}", b.value); // 20

    b.set_childs_to_zero();
    
    println!("a: {}", a.value); // 0
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my confusion but the `child` is simply a reference to the owner right? It isn't cloned?

Comment: Nope, it's not cloned

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong because this is an assumption, but isn't it intended for it to be cloned before you change it (so that way a new object is produced, which is why I assume you want the `child` property in the first place)?

Comment: I added a more detailed example explaining why I would like to avoid copying, hopefully you better understand my issue!

Comment: `&'a mut MyStruct<'a>` is always wrong because it means that the struct is always mutably borrowed for its whole existence, so even if you were able to create it you wouldn't be able to do anything with it. You probably want `Rc<RefCell<MyStruct>>` here.

Comment: Also what you are doing is essentially a linked list, so mandatory reading: [Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a weird way of achieving what you are looking for. I doubt that it is the "right" way but hopefully someone can build off this and provide a better solution.

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;

struct MyStruct {
    value: i32,
    child: Option<Rc<MyStruct>>,
}

impl MyStruct {
    fn add_ten(self) -> (Rc<MyStruct>, MyStruct) {
        let s = Rc::new( self );
        (
            s.clone(),
            MyStruct {
                value: s.value + 10,
                child: Some(s),
            }
        )
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = MyStruct { value: 10, child: None }; // Create some struct
    let (a, b) = a.add_ten(); // Process it and return the new struct with a ref of the child who called it
    
    println!("{}", a.value); // Be able to read the value here
    println!("{}", b.value); // and here
}
```

The use case you are describing is what `Rc` was built for - providing multiple ownership. You can read more about that in the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-04-rc.html).

Comment: Thanks for sharing, it actually was pretty helpful. However, I wasn't able to go to the end of my problem. I added an other example so you can better understand why I wanted to avoid copying.

What I've done is use `Box` and added `set_childs_to_zero` which works, but of course will show: `println!("a: {}", a.value); // 10` at the end.

I'll look more into your approach to see if I can get something to work! Thanks again